# Ruby on Rails: Should a RESTful controller's index action be used for the search page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I have a relatively simple question. I'm building an application with users. I have a User model and a UsersController, which is a RESTful controller for the User model. I want to provide a view in my application that makes it possible to search for other users via username. Would it be good form to use the index action for this page? Or is the index action meant to be reserved for displaying all existing instances of a resource without modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index action is the ideal action for this sort of an action. Usually the index action is meant to return a list of data about a certain resource though a search reduces a result the main point is still to receive a list of results on a resource. So, in that regard that is the ideal action. Secondly, there are no appropriate default routes that can be used for this other than Index. So, if you want you can use a custom route but, that's going to be extra work. In the mean time by using the Index action you are going to reuse the views as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I feel more confident moving forward with this approach now.